# Android: android.app.Dialog.setTitle() doesn't show title of dialog

Tags: android

I am using `android.app.Dialog` and using `setTitle("title");` method but it doesn't show the dialog title bar. I have also used the following style for that activity in menifest file.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

May be this style automatically applies for dialog as well. How can I show the title bar without changing the `windowNoTitle` to `false`? I also don't want to use `AlertDialog` instead of `Dialog`.

Comment: share your code for creating dialog

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your style to
Check this style may be this will work.

```
 <style name="picture_dialog_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorOrange</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/PauseDialogAnimation</item>-->
</style>
```